# How do I OPTIMIZE a 9GB table if the disk has very little free space?

Tags: mysql

I have a 9GB myisam table on a 12GB disk with 5MB free space. How do I `optimize` the table?

The problem is that `OPTIMIZE` works by copying the whole table to a new file, therefore I would need 9GB of free space for this to succeed.

The only solution I can come up with is to

1. stop writes on the table,
2. do a logical backup of the table to another machine
3. drop the table
4. recreate the table by restoring from the backup on the other machine

And in the future I should limit the table size to be smaller than available free space.

Did I answer my question or is there a better solution?
Thanks.

Comment: I should do it exact as you describe.I think this is answer.But you should also consider increase disk space by replacing disk drive, in future your record may grow and you will have more problems then optimizing table.

Answer (score 0):

Drop indexes and restore them manually or by query. This is same with OPTIMIZE operation.