# How to repair the table while having small space on Hard Drive

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-5.7

I have a large datatable of around 60GB. This table had alot of unused rows and after deleting about 6GB of them I have noticed that table size stayed the same (60GB) and their was an "optimize" message within phpmyadmin. So i clicked to optimize, but i didnt have enough space on the hd. So i had to halt the process and restarted mysql.

After i logged back in I happen to have a problem with my table, when I try to access it i get message similar to:
"Table 'table_name' is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed"

Right now I have 3.5GB of space to use on the hard drive. What would be the best way forward to repair, fix and shirt this particular table?

At the moment my plan is to download full database from the server onto a local hard drive; after which I will delete unused data (it will most likely be 59.99GB of it) and then to either copy or re-import data back into live database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you free space exporting only another heavy table and truncate this?
You get more space and after repair affected table you only must import a table, not full database.

Comment: There is only one other large table, which is 13GB. Rest are around few MB in size. I do have some files within database folder /var/lib/mysql/{database} that have names starting with a #:
#sql-1df7_22561.MYD 54GB
#sql-6dc_4c.MYD 6.8GB

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869247/how-do-i-optimize-a-9gb-table-if-the-disk-has-very-little-free-space suggests drop indexes to free space, and make indexes after optimize. Think about everything you can use to free space, delete logs, indexes, anything you may not need or you can recover easy, as index.

Comment: I am also considering deleting all files with a "#sql" after copying over to the local hard drive; i guess they are related to a previous repair process or something like that!?

Comment: I do not know about #sql files. But if you are using phpMyAdmin you can select Structure tab on a table and look Information -> Space usage. As real example, one of my tables in a current project weigths 27.1 Mb, but data is only 19.6 , index is 7.5

Comment: I have (fast) read that #sql files are temporary and may be deleted, but it is on your own.

Comment: Thanks for information Fran. I am waiting for backup of #sql files to complete and I am going to try deleting those. After which I will try to perform a table repair. At the moment I am unable to access the table in question via phpMyAdmin due to it needing a repair.

Comment: I had to delete #sql files, after the backup, after which i was able to perform repair. Now I am having to delete all the unused records and perform repair every time i reach 10GB overhead.